# Selenium: Using the wrong element in for loop

Tags: c#, selenium

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace FlippaSearch
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static IWebDriver driverGC;
    public Form1()
    {
        driverGC = new ChromeDriver(@"Z:\Justin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\chromedriver_win32");
        driverGC.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://flippa.com/websites/starter-sites?sitetype=blog&uniques_per_month_min=1000");
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<IWebElement> starterSites = new List<IWebElement>();
        List<String> myStarterSites = new List<string>();
        IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driverGC, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.00));
        var numPages = (driverGC.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='searchBody']/div[1]/div[1]/h2/span")).Text);
        double numberPages = int.Parse(Regex.Match(numPages, @"\d+", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Value);
        numberPages = Math.Ceiling(numberPages / 50);
        int j;
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberPages; i++)
        {
            driverGC.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            var mySites = driverGC.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".ListingResults___listingResult"));
            int size = 1;
            for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            {
                driverGC.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                mySites = driverGC.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".ListingResults___listingResult"));
                size = mySites.Count();
                driverGC.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                String siteLink = " ";
                siteLink = mySites[j].FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ListingResults___listingResultLink")).GetAttribute("href");

                driverGC.Navigate().GoToUrl(siteLink);
                driverGC.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                //testing tables
                int row_tr = 5;
                int Column_td = 3;
                String CellValue;
                String newCellValue;
                String cellValueChange;
                try
                {
                    driverGC.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/table[1]/tbody"));
                    for (int k = 1; k <= row_tr; k++)
                    {
                        for (int b = 1; b <= Column_td; b++)
                        {
                            CellValue = driverGC.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[" + k + "]/td[" + b + "]")).Text.ToString();
                            if (CellValue == "Organic Search")
                            {
                                String mySiteName = driverGC.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h1")).Text.ToString();
                                newCellValue = driverGC.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[" + k + "]/td[3]")).Text.ToString();
                                cellValueChange = Regex.Replace(newCellValue, @"[%\s]", string.Empty);
                                float organicSearch = float.Parse(cellValueChange);
                                if (organicSearch >= 50)
                                {
                                    myStarterSites.Add(mySiteName);
                                    myStarterSites.Add(CellValue);
                                    myStarterSites.Add(newCellValue);
                                    Console.WriteLine(mySiteName);
                                    Console.WriteLine(CellValue);
                                    Console.WriteLine(newCellValue);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException)
                {

                }
                //testing tables
                driverGC.Navigate().Back();
                //write shit to file
                siteLink = "";
                driverGC.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            }
            j = 0;
            //mySites = null;
            try
            {
                driverGC.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='searchBody']/div[2]/div[2]/div/a[3]")).Click();
                //driverGC.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            }
            catch (ElementNotVisibleException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No more pages");
            }
        }
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\newFile.txt"))
        {
            foreach (string s in myStarterSites)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(s + "  ");// Writes in next line
                writer.WriteLine(" ");
            }
        }
        //MessageBox.Show("End");
        driverGC.Quit();
        Application.Exit();    
    }
}
}
```

Upon starting, the code will run fine on the first page. It grab's the elements, puts them in a list, and then i can gather the required information. Once it loops through the first page (i have it set to 3 strictly for testing reasons so its quicker) it will click next page, and then the next page loads and the loop begins again. The issue is, when the second page loads, the first element on the first page is being checked again, and then after that one is checked, it will go to the 2nd element on the 2nd page, and then continue on from there. My question is, how can i get it to scan the first element on the second page instead of redoing the first element on the first page again? I have tried using Waits but I cannot seem to get anything to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It probably timing issue, the next loop iteration starts before the next page is actually loaded. You can use explicit wait and `ExpectedConditions` `TextToBePresentInElementLocated` on the page numbers to make sure the current page is what you actually need. You can do it by checking the number in the element with `Pagination___activeLink` class

```
driverGC.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='searchBody']/div[2]/div[2]/div/a[3]")).Click(); // go to next page

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementLocated(By.ClassName("Pagination___activeLink"), (i + 1).ToString()));
```